# resend messages from telegram chats to bot chat telegram

Tags: python, telegram-bot

How can I make it so that messages are forwarded from a group or chat to my chat bot, otherwise now I can only send messages from a chat bot to groups

```
import telebot

# Токен бота
token = ''

keywords = ['crypto', 'artem']

chat_id_source =  # ID исходного канала
chat_id_destination =   # ID чата вашего бота

# Инициализация бота    
bot = telebot.TeleBot(token)


@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start_handler(message):
    # Здесь можно загрузить список контактов бота и список контактов, добавленных в контакты

    # Отправка приветственного сообщения
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Привет! Бот запущен')


message_set = set()  # Initialize a set to store unique messages


def send_message_to_bot(message):
    # Отправка сообщения в ваш телеграм-бот
    bot.send_message(chat_id_destination, message.text)


@bot.message_handler(func=lambda message: True)
def forward_message(message):
    if any(keyword in message.text.lower() for keyword in keywords):
        if message.from_user is not None and message.from_user.username is not None:
            sender_username = message.from_user.username
            chat_members = bot.get_chat_member(chat_id_source, message.from_user.id)
            if (
                sender_username not in bot.get_chat(chat_id_source).username
                and not message.from_user.is_bot
                and chat_members.status not in ['left', 'kicked', 'administrator']
            ):
                # Check if the message is unique
                if message.text not in message_set:
                    message_set.add(message.text)  # Add the message to the set

                    # Отправляем сообщение в канал
                    bot.send_message(chat_id_source, message.text)

        else:
            print(f"Received message from {sender_username}: {message.text}")


# Запуск бота с использованием Long Polling
bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```

How can I make it so that messages are forwarded from a group or chat to my chat bot, otherwise now I can only send messages from a chat bot to groups

Comment: You left your **Private Bot Token** in your code. You should revoke it **ASAP** by talking to the [@BotFather](https://t.me/BotFather). People might abuse the token.